# PHP class not found on windows but not on linux when using namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have recently been working on a front end application on a linux environment which uses namespaces to structure it's classes. There were no problems including files. However I have cloned the same site to my windows machine (using xampp php 5.4) and I am getting the error below. The application uses an autoload function. The class is inside the namespace 'core' and resides in a folder named 'core' outside of the web root and in the same directory as the Autoloader.php file. The autoload function is as follows:

```
public function autoLoad($name){
    if (!$this->requiredLibrariesLoaded) {
        $this->requireLibraries();
    }
    $path = NULL;
    $namespaceParts = explode('\\', $name);
    $pathTail = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespaceParts) . '.php';

    $tryPath = $this->rootPath . '/' . $pathTail;

    if(is_readable($tryPath)){
        $path = $tryPath;
    }
    else echo $tryPath."\n";

    if ($path) {
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        // throw new Exception("Class $name does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Fatal error: Class 'core\AlternativeParser' not found

I am unable to work out why I am getting this fatal error. I suppose what I maybe should be asking is is there anything about switching from a linux environment to a windows environment which could potentially be causing namespace issues?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it will be more simpel for you to use __ dir __ ? 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: I have found what the problem was. Somebody had been using <? opening tags instead of <?php and it was throwing an obscure error in my windows environment. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.